# Dynamically add javascript functions to an Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's say that I have an angular service, this service calls a servlet asking for a library.js file containing my custom JavaScript functions.
Is there any way I can dynamically add these functions to my Angular application at run-time? 
For example, in the library.js file I might have the following custom function:

```
helloWorld(){
    alert("hello world");
}
```

It should work as follows:

1) I call the servlet using the standard Angular module HttpClient

2) The servlet sends back library.js, containing a list of functions, like helloWorld();

3) The angular web applications loads the library.js file (how?)

4) I can then call the helloWorld() function in my angular code.

Comment: are you asking about DI and returning functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [runtime load components or modules into a module in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630165/runtime-load-components-or-modules-into-a-module-in-angular2)

Comment: @TKoL nice find. dunno if duplicate since it's unclear above if it's runtime package adding we're talking about.

Comment: @rekotc could be clearer.

Comment: I'm editing the question to make it clearer

Comment: The question is pretty clear. Can a jar file or for that matter any script called from the server be invoked at runtime by angular? It should be, but how?

Comment: Actually the link @Tkol has shared probably could be of some help. It is a brilliant link.

Comment: Just define all methods in class helper, and call them when you get response. I dont see any problems.

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this? It sounds like it will be messy. Why are you insisting on loading via `HttpClient`, when you could (maybe, subject to Angular restrictions) load by simply inserting a `<script>` tag into the DOM?

Comment: @torazaburo I don't have a static .js file to include in the project. ideally, i'd like to generate the library.js dynamically server side (and this is not a problem) and deliver it to the angular application at runtime via a servlet.

Comment: What I'm saying is, you can insert a `script` tag with a `src` of something like `http://my-server/servlet/dynamic-javascript.jsp`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we were able to solve the problem in the following way:

1) The servlet answers with the following message, the script tags are MANDATORY, it won't be recognized as valid js code otherwise.

```
String servletAnswer = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function helloWorld(){
    alert("custom message!");
}
</script>"
```

2) The angular application subscribes and waits for the servlet to answer in the usual way. As soon as i get the response i do:

```
var script = response;
$('body').append(script);     /* i append the script to body of the document,
                              now the function helloWorld is available to the application */
```

3) I call the function using eval:

```
 eval("helloWorld()");
```

I hope it helps! Thanks everybody